# How to get user's plain password in PDO class of Sabre DAV?

Tags: php, sabredav

How can I get hold of the current logged-in user's plaintext password in the following file of Sabre DAV library?

```
https://github.com/sabre-io/dav/tree/master/lib/CardDAV/Backend

in Baikal, this file is at:
\baikal\vendor\sabre\dav\lib\CardDAV\Backend\PDO.php
```

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Sabre\CardDAV\Backend;

use Sabre\CardDAV;
use Sabre\DAV;
use Sabre\DAV\PropPatch;

/**
 * PDO CardDAV backend.
 *
 * This CardDAV backend uses PDO to store addressbooks
 *
 * @copyright Copyright (C) fruux GmbH (https://fruux.com/)
 * @author Evert Pot (http://evertpot.com/)
 * @license http://sabre.io/license/ Modified BSD License
 */
class PDO extends AbstractBackend implements SyncSupport
...
...
}
```

Comment: If you were able to get a user's plaintext password from that library, then no one would be using it. What is the purpose of getting this value? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to achieve encryption using user's pw. So actually I'm trying to increase security.

Comment: Are you saying that this library is using plain text passwords and you want to hash it for some other purpose (note that encryption and hashing aren't the same things, encryptions is reversible, while hashing isn't)?

Comment: I am asking a specific question regarding this webdav implementation. A comment or answer would preferably direct me in changing some constructors or setting some global vars. If you need to know more about this library, you can look it up at the link I gave (lib is sabre-io). This library authenticates using plain password which is then hashed to match the stored password.

Comment: Please share more details - why should any database store passwords in plaintext? The consequences would be horrible, so nobody would use it, and even you shouldn't

Comment: The database does not (and obviously should not) store passwords in plaintext, but the passwords do arrive in plain text via HTTP Basic auth (TLS secured of coursed).

Comment: Yeah, and why not store that password then in the session if you need it?

Comment: hnh is right. Passwords arrive in plain text and they will be used for encryption and decryption of some vcard data. Session as @NicoHaase says could be a place to keep this plain text. I chose a global variable for my needs but may switch to session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Basic Authentication, the file is this:

\baikal\Core\Frameworks\Baikal\Core\PDOBasicAuth.php

plain password is at the validateUserPass function and it can be stored at a global var (or in the session as mentioned in the comments of the question):

```
function validateUserPass($username, $password) {
        
        global $ptp;
        
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT username, digesta1 FROM ' . $this->tableName . ' WHERE username = ?');
        $stmt->execute([$username]);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        if (!count($result)) {
            return false;
        }

        $hash = md5($username . ':' . $this->authRealm . ':' . $password);
        if ($result[0]['digesta1'] === $hash) {
            $this->currentUser = $username;
            
            $ptp = $password;
                    
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, at the \baikal\vendor\sabre\dav\lib\CardDAV\Backend\PDO.php file, the value of the $ptp var can be retrieved using `global $ptp;`