# Is there a way to implement carddav client in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, carddav

We are building an application with react native, and we have shared contacts on our server, we are trying to sync contacts using carddav protocol, i could not find a library that allow such operation for react native.
Is there any ideas on how this can be implemented?

Comment: to read the contacts in react native you can use this package [react-native-contacts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-contacts).  To implement that steps are [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-native-contacts-how-to-access-a-devices-contact-list/).

Comment: @fixedDrill thanks for your comment, we have already implemented this for the contacts on the device, now we need to access contacts on the server using carddav protocol

Comment: tried this tips? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346947/how-to-implement-encryption-on-baikal-sabredav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346947/how-to-implement-encryption-on-baikal-sabredav).

Comment: Our problem is not about the encryption or the server side. Mainly i cannot find a way to use carddav in react-native, the available libraries for client side are those for the browser or node. Also i see that ios devices support adding a contacts account using carddav manually in the contacts settings, but i cannot find a way to trigger that programmatically using react-native.